# Finding capacitors with low soakage (dielectric absorption)

Tags: capacitor

[This technical note from Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-090.pdf) indicates that low dielectric absorption is a prime requirement for choosing a capacitor for a sample-and-hold circuit (see page 11).  It also suggests to look for capacitors advertised as low dielectric absorption.

How do I go about searching for capacitors designed for low dielectric absorption?  On Digikey and Mouser, it's not one of the listed parameters.

I also tried searching based on dielectric type, based on information from [Kemet](http://www.kemet.com/kemet/web/homepage/kfbk3.nsf/cf929d17eb7088c9852568110058afbb/1b549c30108633ea85256a8700515cf5/%24FILE/DilectAbsorp.pdf) and Wikipedia linking dielectric absorption to material.  In this case, it seems like film capacitors are the best candidates (still can't find any datasheets that actually report absorption), but they have very low capacitance.  Ideally I want 1uF or more capacitance, to limit the effects of charge injection from the analog switching logic.

What terms and parameters should I use to guide my search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dielectrics with the lowest absorption are vacuum and air (which is jinxed in normal conditions by porcelain, glass or sapphire). Out of normal dielectrics, Teflon was the best in the last century. There have possibly been some improvements made for polypropylene and polyester caps. There is an article by Bob Pease about the phenomena http://electronicdesign.com/article/analog-and-mixed-signal/what-s-all-this-soakage-stuff-anyhow-6096

So your solution may involve Teflon or normal plastics. But if you are designing a new 9 digit voltmeter, then the capacitor design becomes very interesting, as interesting as a real analog trade secret can be.

BTW, the percentages for DA cited on Analog Devices pages are in the range of 0.001%...

Comment: You have any idea where to look for the papers formerly found in the "good technical stuff" section of his website, which no longer can be found at www.national.com/rap ?

Comment: Found it: [The Best of Bob Pease](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/www-national-com_rap.pdf), linked from http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/index.html

Comment: And where are these Analog Devices datasheets with 0.001% DA?  AFAIK, Analog doesn't make capacitors...

Comment: http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/Anniversary/21.html at the end of page there is list of dielectrics

Answer (score 2):

The best are Teflon, followed by polystyrene and polypropylene.  Polyester is not so good.  Ceramics are also bad.  Only polypropylene is really easy to find.
Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: Multi Layer Ceramic Capacitors (MLCC) NP0/C0G are somewhat in the middle in terms of Dielectric Absorption, worse than plastic/thin film but definitively much better than high-K MLCC.