# How do I find capacitors for low dielectric absorption?

Tags: capacitor, precision

I'm looking through digikey's option on polypropylene capacitors.

None of them seem to specify dielectric absorption.

This is for a low voltage sample-hold circuit. Low leakage is good, but low dielectric absorption is more important.  I cannot seem to figure out the difference between PP, Metalized PP, and Stacked PP capacitors.

I'm seeking advice for specific capacitors or a way to decipher the datasheet.  For instance, does the voltage rating tend to matter? Does lower leakage/higher insulation resistance tend to mean a better dielectric absorption specification?

Thank you

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39586/finding-capacitors-with-low-soakage-dielectric-absorption for a discussion. Teflon seems to be the winner. For general interest and information, Bob Pease at http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/www-national-com_rap.pdf talks about different dielectric materials (and so much more!) and why they're important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dielectric absorption in high K ceramic makes them poor for S&H caps.

Electrolytics all have this property but worse.  Teflon is the closest to ideal cap  with the lowest Dielectric Absorption.  Followed by Polypropylene and NPO Ceramic.

[image]
The error above is plotted for a 1V step signal into a S&H.

The above was reported by RAP in ED magazine but written in 1982.  I have known this since the late 70's from Mil-Std Hdbk's on Capacitor material properties and had worked with long RC integrators and fast ADC S&H's.

If you need small tolerances use NPO ceramic. If you need better performance than above, negative feedback circuits exist to compensate for this property.

[image]

Comment: The 'sample A/sample B' spread in mylar, polystyrene, NP0...  is significant, in that graph.   If one were to buy a PTFE (Teflon) capacitor today, it might be 'sample B'?  Brandname/model info seems to be needed.

Comment: Caps improved a lot since 1982 but D.A. may not have changed much. The old brands would be obsolete.  Besides the spread is only <0.02% error after 100us

Comment: A recent TI App Note indicated "DA is specified as a
percentage of the charging voltage. It can range from a low of 0.02% for Teflon,
polystyrene, and polypropylene capacitors, up to a high of 10% or more for some
electrolytics. For some time frames, the DA of polystyrene can be as low as 0.002%.
Common high-K ceramics and polycarbonate capacitor types display typical DA on the
order of 0.2%"  in 6567.Dielectric-Absorption-in-Caps.pdf

Comment: It's not only 100 us; some sample capacitors will see low-slew inputs, so a bias voltage applied for many seconds is possible.   A 'reset' phase between conversions becomes important (as in a dual-slope or Wilkinson converter).

Comment: True but DA tests use a long soak time and this log scale makes it look worse, but is still a valid source of errors in high res. ADC's which ought to train young engineers to verify accuracy with a wide range of test patterns for repeatability errors with different input patterns. I recall using sawtooths and butterfly step signals to compare ADC & DAC for error differences and discovered many hidden flaws in BB ADC hybrids when they were one of the best in class at the time.

Comment: Note that the curves use might not use same C values but actually value dependent for knee of R2C2=T for DA being much longer than T=ESR*C1 if you consider fundamental cap value C1 and its associated ESR is perhaps >>1000x faster than the DA time constant of >>1ms. I know this is not clear.  but T=ESR* C can range from <<100ns to 1us for ultra low ESR caps